# HNQ link refreshes page

Tags: bug, mobile-web, hot-questions

For a few days now, I've been having a weird problem. I previously thought it my be just my device, as I'm not having similar problems on my desktop machine, but [@PhiNotPi managed to reproduce.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38567545#38567545)

Sometimes, when I browse the desktop version of Code Golf and click on one of the links in the Hot Network Questions list, the target URL appears briefly in my browser's address bar, everything flashes, and the browser refreshes the old page. There's no history entry or indication of what happened. To make matters worse, the HNQ list has been rotated by the time the page refreshed, so I'm left without the distraction I asking for.

This is an intermittent bug, as all of this happens only once out of every 10 or 20 HNQ links I click. In case it matters, I'm using Chrome 59.0.3071.125 on Android 6.0.1.

Comment: I have reproduced the bug at least once, and I'm also using Chrome 59.0.3071.125 on Android 6.0.1.